# hasMany relation loopback

Tags: node.js, strongloop, loopbackjs

**My models.json:**

My models.json

```
"masterTrip": {
    "options": {
        "relations": {
            "trips": {
                "type": "hasMany",
                "model": "trip",
                "foreignKey": "masterTripId"
            }
        }
    }
},
"trip": {
    "options": {
        "relations": {
            "masterTrips": {
                "type": "belongsTo",
                "model": "masterTrip",
                "foreignKey": "masterTripId"
            }
        }
    }
},
```

But I do not get the relation between the trip and mastertrip. can anybody explain?

Comment: Can you elaborate 'I do not get the relation between the trip and mastertrip'? BTW, you'll probably find the following blog useful: http://strongloop.com/strongblog/defining-and-mapping-data-relations-with-loopback-connected-models/

Comment: when I access masterTrips?filter[include]=trips, trips is empty "trips": []

Comment: Have you created any trips associated with the masterTrip? You can find a full example at https://github.com/strongloop-community/loopback-example-datagraph

Comment: I have following documentation strongloop. When use GET /model-name/instance-ID/belongsToRelationName is success, but when I want to agregate GET /model1-name?filter[include]=belongsToRelationName is return []

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple things that might be the problem. Here is what comes to mind:

- You should only need the foreign key on the model that belongsTo the other one.  (In this case, that would be *trip*.)
- Have you actually created trips underneath masterTrip?  (Either in the code itself or via the API?) I know this sounds silly, but the context wasn't clear enough for me to tell if you had created the sample data or not.
- It sounds like you might actually be getting data when you do a GET on `/masterTrip/1/trips`  Is that right?  If so , then that sounds like the correct behavior.

I'm still relatively new to LoopBack myself, but I'm not sure that `filter[include]=belongsToRelationName` is the correct way to get the data you want.  Technically, you are just looking for the associated array of hasMany data, right?  In this case, **trips** that belongTo **masterTrip**.  The RESTful way to get that would be `masterTrip/{id}/trips`

Hope one of those helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your "belongs to" relation name is not singular.  It should be singular.

When you making " belongs to " relation name is singular and for hasMany your relation name in plural. Please see the official documentation for more details -

See this working example below -

```js
{
  "name": "Booking",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "strict": false,
  "idInjection": true,
  "properties": {
    "myuserId": {
      "type": "number"
    },
    "orgin": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "orgin_lat": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "orgin_lon": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "destination": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "dest_lat": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "dest_lon": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "parcel_type": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "volume": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "weight": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "price": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "receiver_phn": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "payment_mode": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "booking_status": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "lang": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "booking_no": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "cancel_reason": {
      "type": "string"
    },
     "cancel_by": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "booking_date": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "plan_later": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "plan_date": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "created": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "modified": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
      "biddings": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "Bidding",
      "foreignKey": "bookingId"
    }
  },
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

```js
{
  "name": "Bidding",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "strict": false,
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "myuserId": {
      "type": "number"
    },
    "bookingId": {
      "type": "number"
    },
    "booking_no": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "price": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "message": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "bid_date": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "bid_time": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "bid_status": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "lang": {
      "type": "string"
    },
     "rate_driver": {
      "type": "number"
    },
    "created": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "modified": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "booking": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "Booking",
      "foreignKey": "bookingId"
    },
    "myuser": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "Myuser",
      "foreignKey": "myuserId"
    }
 
  },
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```